# Genetic Algorithm does not find suitable weights for Neural Network

Tags: optimization, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to use a Genetic Algorithm for finding optimal weights of a Neural Network. The fitness function is the mean square error of the training results. I use truncation to get rid of the worst half of the genes and afterwards I use  Roulette selection. I'm using a mutation rate of 0.01 and uniform crossover.
Unfortunately, the GA does not find any suitable solution. (I ran the GA 5 times with 1000 generations and a population size of 100 and no gene was good. The MSE is 10 times higher than for the weights I found using Backpropagation)
The GA worked well on finding the minimum of the Drop-Wave function and Levy Function 13 but performs poorly on the ANN weights. How can I improve the GA or the fitness function to make it work?

Comment: Population size of 100 and a mutation rate of 0.01? So every generation an average of 1 genome will be mutated... in my experience, this is an extremely low mutation rate. And what exactly is the goal of your fitness function (what do you want the NN to solve?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The NN trys to fit Oil Price returns. I just tried it with a mutation rate of 0.3 but the GA still does not find any suitable set of weights

Comment: What programming language are you using? Could you share your code?